# Sketching solutions to IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Consider the following initial value problem (IVP): $$u_t + \cos(t)u_x = −u, \, \, \, \, (x,t) ∈\mathbb R×(0,∞)$$ $u(x,0) = u_0(x)$, $x ∈\mathbb R$, where $u_0 : \mathbb R → \mathbb R$ is a prescribed smooth and bounded function. Sketch the domain diagram for IVP, indicating the curve $Γ_0$ for IVP. Show that the family of characteristic curves for IVP are given by $γ_s : (x,t) = (\sin(t) + s,t)$, $(t,s) ∈ [0,∞)×\mathbb R$. Sketch the characteristic curves on the domain diagram for IVP. Hence, or otherwise, obtain the solution $u : \mathbb R×[0,∞) → \mathbb R$ to IVP. **Describe the structure of the solution to IVP.**

---

I am stuck on the bold part because I have no idea how to sketch the solution. The solution is: $$u(x,t)=u_0(x-\sin(t))e^{-t}$$which I am pretty sure is correct.

How am I supposed to describe the structure when it seems impossible to sketch this stuff. On the solutions, it was sketched as $u(x,t)$ being the vertical axis and $x$ being the horizontal axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an answer to the question of sketching the solution.

This is the analytical solution of the EDP :

$$u_t+\cos(t)u_x=-u$$
Solving with the method of characteristics :

The characteristic system of differential equations is :
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{\cos(t)}=\frac{du}{-u}$$

First characteristic equation :

From $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{\cos(t)}\qquad\to\qquad  dx-\cos(t)dt=0\qquad\to\qquad  x-\sin(t)=c_1$

Second characteristic equation :

From $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{du}{-u}\qquad\to\qquad  \frac{du}{u}+dt=0 \qquad\to\qquad  e^{t}u=c_2$

General solution on implicit form, with any differentiable function $\phi(X,Y)$ :
$$\Phi\left(x-\sin(t)\:,\:e^{t}u \right)=0$$
Solving for $Y$ :
$$e^t u=F\left(x-\sin(t)\right)$$
where $F$ is any differentiable function.

General solution on explicit form :
$$u(x,t)=e^{-t}F\left(x-\sin(t)\right)$$

Taking account of the condition $u(x,0)=u_0(x)$ where $u_0(x)$ is a given function :
$$u(x,0)=e^{-0}F\left(x-\sin(0)\right)=u_0(x)\qquad\to\qquad F(x)=u_0(x)$$
Hense :
$$u(x,t)=e^{-t}u_0\left(x-\sin(t)\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

I would describe it as follows: as $t$ increases,

- The profile decays exponentially, but keeps the shape of the profile of the initial value.
- It moves in a periodic way right and left up to one unit with speed $\cos t$.

Comment: How did you deduce the second bullet point?

Comment: The graph of $f(x-a)$, $a>0$, is the graph of $f$ translated $a$ units to the right. The profile of $f(x-t)$ is the profile of $f$ moving to the right at speed 1.